# Prevent Magento2 display information on script on homepage

Tags: magento2, security, script, print

I would like to know how can i stop magento2 to printing information about my plugin and script on homepage.If u analyze my code i have got all these script that contain information about all plugin i use.

[image: script]

I thought going on production mode should stop printing this info but it's not working.Please suggest me.

Comment: i see that there are differenct script inside head section and i don't think all these script should appear on my website  ![1]https://i.imgur.com/Jnh2fv4.png

Answer (score 1):

You can **merge the JavaScript files**. This will, generate one big JavaScript file instead of a lot of seperate ones. However, if someone opens the merged file they will still be able to see what modules you use.

To merge JavaScript files, go to:

```
Stores Configuration > Stores > Developer >  Advanced > JavaScript Settings
```

Set Merge JavaScript Files field, select Yes

You need to enable developer mode to see the option in the admin panel. Switch back to production mode afterwards.